# HTML 5 - Skip weekends in input date

Tags: html

how can I skip weekends in input date? I want only first 5 days in week (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday)

How can I do it? I've found something with

`<input type="date" skip="something">`

But I don't understand how to use it.
Thanks.